# C# Add STS Reference Missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure

I have Visual Studio 2010 installed on Windows 7 (32 bit) VM. I have installed Windows Identity Foundation Add-in which I cross checked from Add-in manager of Visual Studio 2010.

When I right click on the project in solution explorer, Add STS reference is missing.

According to the documentation in step 8:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg429779.aspx#BKMK_2

I need to add STS reference. But the option is missing from the context menu. Please help.

Thanks in advance for your help... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: It was a silly mistake. The Project should be created as Windows Azure Cloud Project.

In the step 7 of link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg429779.aspx#BKMK_2

It is not specified that "Cloud" should be selected under "C#" or "Visual Basic" which led me to confusion.

Now the context menu shows "Add STS reference" when I right click on the project name in the explorer window, as the project is a Windows Azure Project type.